# Finding a unique representation as a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

ok, another problem suggested by my prof. 
the vectors $u_1 = (1,1,1,1)$, $u_2 = (0,1,1,1)$, $u_3 = (0,0,1,1)$, $u_4 = (0,0,0,1)$, are a basis for $F^4$.

Find a unique representation of an arbitrary vector $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ as a linear combination of $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$.

OK, as I understand it I have to find some scalar coefficients such that 
$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ = $c_n(u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + u_4)$ = $c_1(1,1,1,1) + c_2(0,1,1,1) + c_3(0,0,1,1) +c_4(0,0,0,1)$, correct?

assuming that is the case, though, I get stuck. if I just add the u-vectors I get (1, 2, 3, 4) but I am unsure what to do after that. I feel like this should be simple but I have been so bloody lost in this class..

Comment: Gauss-eliminate until you're at (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1), keeping track of your steps; then it becomes trivial.

Comment: and a Gauss estimate is...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $a_1u_1$ or else you won't get the right first coefficient.  The only way to get $a_2$ in the second coefficient is by taking $u_2$, but if you take $a_2u_2$ you'll get $a_1+a_2$ in the second coefficient, which is too many.  Hence, you must take $(a_2-a_1)u_2$, which will give you just $a_2$ in the second coefficient when added to $a_1$ from the $u_1$ previously.

Continuing in this way you will get $$a_1u_1+(a_2-a_1)u_2+(a_3-a_2)u_3+(a_4-a_3)u_4$$

Comment: yes, I think I see better what is happening now. thanks. i was a little panicky.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused. Given $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, you need to find $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ such that $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = c_1(1,1,1,1) + c_2(0,1,1,1) + c_3(0,0,1,1) + c_4(0,0,0,1)$. The expression "$c_n(u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4)$" is wrong, and should be deleted entirely.

Comment: yes completely utterly and totally confused in this class is about the size of it. but doing a little algebra I would get a1 = c1, a2 = c1+ c2 and a3 = c1 + c2 + c3 and a4 = c1+ c2 + c3 + c4. Is that the right direction?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now $c_1 = a_1$. So what's $c_2$ (in terms of $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$)? $c_3$? $c_4$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The basis $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$ can be written as $u_1-u_2$, $u_2-u_3$, $u_3-u_4$, $u_4$.